# Accumulate results according to index value

Tags: vba, excel

I have column indexes such as VENTA, TOTAL, VACUNA (sales, total, vaccines) and at the end a TOTAL PER ROW **(3)**, I want that total to be autogenerated, but the way the data is charged is not conventional, and is as it follows:

- Cells on sales are negative numbers and indicate a specific amount of things sold **(1)**
- Cells on total and vaccines indicates totality to a specific date **(2)**

That's why I needed to create a VBA script that whenever there's a sale I need to autoupdate the TOTAL PER ROW **(3)** according to the last total **(2)** I had (being total or vaccines)

This is the code I created (it's really hardcoded I know), and I am having a compilation error:

```
Sub CalculoTotal()
Dim ultima As Long, v As Long, c As Long, ventas(5 To 10) As Long
ultima = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For c = 5 To 10
    ventas(c) = 0
Next c
For v = ultima - 2 To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(2, v).Value = "VENTA" Then
        For c = 5 To 10
            ventas(c) = ventas(c) + Cells(c, v + 1).Value
        Next c
        If Cells(2, v - 1).Value = "TOTAL" Or Cells(2, v - 1).Value = "VACUNA" Then
            For c = 5 To 10
                Cells(c, ultima).Value = Cells(c, v - 1).Value + ventas(c)
            Next c
            Exit For
        End If
    Else
        For c = 5 To 10
            Cells(c, ultima).Value = Cells(c, v).Value
        Next c
        Exit For
    End If
Next v
End Sub
```

In order for you to understand better here it is my table
[image]

Or do you think there is an easier way of achieving this task?

*EDIT: I think that it would be much easier if I ask for the column of the last VENTA, TOTAL, or VACUNA and according to it just do the subtraction. Is there a way of doing this?
Also the code as it is I've realized it's wrong because there might be some empty cells on VACUNA and the total would display 0 but for that specific cell it would have to be the last TOTAL of that row.*

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem using the second approach which is much clearer

```
Function LastTotal() As Variant
Dim ultima As Long, v As Long
ultima = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For v = ultima - 2 To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(2, v).Value = "TOTAL" Then
        LastTotal = v
        Exit For
    End If
Next v
End Function

Function LastVacuna() As Variant
Dim ultima As Long, v As Long
ultima = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For v = ultima - 2 To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(2, v).Value = "VACUNA" Then
        LastVacuna = v
        Exit For
    End If
Next v
End Function

Function LastVenta() As Variant
Dim ultima As Long, v As Long
ultima = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For v = ultima - 2 To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(2, v).Value = "VENTA" Then
        LastVenta = v
        Exit For
    End If
Next v
End Function

Public Sub CalculoTotal()
Dim ultima As Long, venta As Long, vacuna As Long, total As Long, ventas(5 To 10) As Long, c As Long
ultima = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
venta = LastVenta()
vacuna = LastVacuna()
total = LastTotal()
If total > vacuna And total > venta Then
    For c = 5 To 10
        Cells(c, ultima).Value = Cells(c, total).Value
    Next c
ElseIf venta > total And total > vacuna Then
    For c = 5 To 10
        Cells(c, ultima).Value = Cells(c, total).Value + Cells(c, venta).Value
    Next c
ElseIf venta > vacuna And vacuna > total Then
    For c = 5 To 10
        If Cells(c, vacuna) = "" Then
            Cells(c, ultima).Value = Cells(c, total).Value + Cells(c, venta).Value
        Else
            Cells(c, ultima).Value = Cells(c, vacuna).Value + Cells(c, venta).Value
        End If
    Next c
ElseIf vacuna > total And total > venta Then
    For c = 5 To 10
        If Cells(c, vacuna) = "" Then
            Cells(c, ultima).Value = Cells(c, total).Value
        Else
            Cells(c, ultima).Value = Cells(c, vacuna).Value
        End If
    Next c
ElseIf vacuna > total And venta > total Then
    For c = 5 To 10
        If Cells(c, vacuna) = "" Then
            Cells(c, ultima).Value = Cells(c, total).Value + Cells(c, venta).Value
        Else
            Cells(c, ultima).Value = Cells(c, vacuna).Value + Cells(c, vacuna).Value
        End If
    Next c
End If
End Sub
```